# Given Wittgenstein's characterisation of language as essentially public, can he characterise what form thinking takes?

Tags: philosophy-of-language, consciousness, wittgenstein, private-language

According to Wittgenstein, language is an essentially public activity between minds; and language is structured by a grammar so that this communication can indeed occur. I think, the notion of language is equivalent to grammar (a  structuring); as grammar stipulates the range and form of the expression of the language.

But minds also think, and this is a private activity; so it cannot be of the form of any kind of language, and so cannot have any kind of grammar, hence any kind of structuring.

Does he make the claim that thinking cannot be rationally explicated to *any* extent, ie given some kind of structure?

(I'm tempted to conflate thinking with conciousness, but I think that would be a mistake.)

Comment: Following Wittgenstein, language is public because there can't be a private language. Also, meaning is given by *use*. He refers to 'private language'in Philosophical Investigations (§259, etc).

Answer (score 6):

> But minds also think, and this is a private activity

What's more, Wittgenstein makes this argument explicitly with his "Beetle Box" thought experiment (in the *Philosophical Investigations*.)  And, what's more, he also shows that much thought is not of a propositional nature, and does not work well with traditional notions of epistemology; one cannot be mistaken about having one's tooth ache.

> Does he make the claim that thinking cannot be rationally explicated to *any* extent, ie given some kind of structure?

No he does not, and the fact that we are able to discuss his writings here and now demonstrates that *his* thinking can be rationally explicated to some extent; the claim that you suggest would be self-defeating.

I'd recommend that you have a go at the *Philosophical Investigations*-- it is that very rare kind of book that matches a high degree of accessibility (it is fairly easy to follow Wittgenstein's arguments, and does not require any particular knowledge of the prior philosophical tradition) with some very serious challenges to traditional ways of seeing things.

Comment: I think this answer is a little misleading. Nowhere does Wittgenstein suggest that thinking is a private activity.  It can be private, but it can also be public - such as when, for example, I choose to express my thoughts. In that case, they are no longer private (it really is that simple).

Comment: I don't think it's *quite* that simple, as the "expression of the thoughts" is not identical to the thoughts themselves-- which is why I framed the answer the way I did: thinking is private, but it can be rationally explicated when expressed. I'll edit for clarity, though.

Comment: The expression is of course distinct from the thought.  It is what makes the thought public.  But the thought itself becomes public! He made his thoughts on his marriage public on the talk show, etc. As W says, "So someone can hide his thoughts from me by expressing them in a language I don't know. But where is the mental thing which is hidden?" (RPP vol 2, 564) This seems to me to be important in grasping W's view of thinking.

Comment: I read W as arguing that expressions are *not* reducible to thoughts; the mental thing is *not* hidden by expressing the thoughts in a foreign language; they are hidden because they are mental, and only partially expressed.  If a lion could speak, we could not understand him.

Comment: I believe that you said as much in your own answer; there is no single true representation, nor need there be.

Comment: I do think you're misreading W here Michael.  The mental is not something that is essentially 'hidden'.  Hence the rhetorical question 'where is the mental thing which is hidden?'. The mental is only contingently hidden by such things as not expressing a thought or expressing it in a way incomprehensible to others.  I'm sure expressions are not reducible to thoughts, as you say; W surely doesn't think so either. Expression reveals our thoughts, makes them public. Our point of difference seems rather to hang on whether the mental is essentially private for W (I say it is not).

Comment: The 'beetle in the box' analogy is about sensation, not thinking. Its point is not to show that sensation is essentially private, but that "the model of object and designation" is not applicable to the words 'beetle in a box', for they would be meaningless. Hence that model not applicable to sensation language either (an argument against private language). We could not understand a talking lion because it belongs to very different forms of life, not because its mental life is essentially hidden.

Comment: The fact that the sensation is private means that there can be no agreement upon a shared signified (to use Saussure's terms.)  Meanwhile, while the lion belongs to a very different form of life, our inability to agree on shared signified means that *any* form of life may, in fact, be very different: as Derrida says, *tout autre est tout autre.*

Comment: @Dorfman: When I say thought cannot be rationally explicated, I do not mean the translation from thought to language. I'm asking whether thought itself can be given some rational structure. For example, the language spoken by englishmen can be given a rational structure - a grammar. I'm arguing that if thought itself can be given some structure, then in some sense it could seen as a grammar of thought, ie a language; but language is public; so it cannot be.

Comment: @MichaelDorfman I'm not sure now if we are still discussing W's view or we have moved on.  W certainly did not think of sensation as essentially private (e.g. "If I see someone writhing in pain I do not think: All the same, his feelings are hidden from me").  What you say about the "shared signified" is solipsism. PI 22 shows that W did not think there was any such thing as a "shared signified" (or sentence radical) to disagree about.

Answer (score 1):

> Does he make the claim that thinking cannot be rationally explicated to any extent, ie given some kind of structure?

It is important to understand with Wittgenstein that he has a particular understanding of 'explanation' which differs from that most commonly found in analytic philosophy. Commonly, 'explanations' are given by formal analysis - most typically, in recent decades, giving the structure of sentences or propositions in terms of a calculus (this holds true of logical positivism and truth conditional semantics, the two main strands of linguistic analysis in the 20th century).

Wittgenstein, by contrast, sees such activities as providing not inner structures but *representations* of language - he stresses that there is no *single* true representation and nor need there be.  A 'proposition' is a 'family resemblance' concept and has no single structure or essence.  Explanation of language, for Wittgenstein, is given through showing the underlying grammar (which differs from the superficial or 'surface grammar') of sentences. Grammar, in this sense, is determined by how the sentence is really used (not only by philosophers!), and what connections it has with other sentences.

It would be mistaken, on such an account, to think there is a grammar of thinking. If one wishes to understand what thinking is, one could look to the uses of the word 'thinking' and its cognates. Philosophy has no other means of explaining a term. If there is some other discipline, a science or empricial psychology, which can explicate thinking and any 'structure' it may have, then that is fine, but not the domain of Wittgenstein's investigations and not the domain of philosophy.

Comment: so, for 'Grammar, in this sense, is determined by how the sentence is really used', you're talking for _descriptive grammars_, and against _prescriptive grammars_?

Comment: I don't think W uses that distinction. If we describe a use, that description (if correct) can be made into a rule for use. These rules are constitutive of meaning. Divergences between actual use and correct use - between descriptive and prescriptive grammars - are not differences of meaning. So they are not the 'grammatical rules' W has in mind.

Comment: I can't see how rules or a grammar can constitute meaning, is this what W is argueing for?

Comment: Yes. Meaning is determined by use. The use of a word is determined by the rules for the use of that word.  Using words in speech is a rule governed activity.  The rules for use are constitutive of what W calls 'grammar' - this is an idiosyncratic use of the term 'grammar' however.  These rules determine what combinations of expressions are allowed and disallowed, i.e. which ones makes sense and which don't e.g. 'door' can go with 'open' but not with 'happy'.  One of W's greatest insights is that what appear to be necessary truths are in general grammatical rules.

Comment: Ok, hows does this work with 'two and two are four'? Surely this is a neccessary truth of logic, and not language; or are you subsuming logic under language?

Comment: W's philosophy of mathematics is very extensive but it is consistent with his view of language. 2+2=4 is not a necessary truth of logic, as the mathematical platonists like to say.  Its 'necessity' is no more than a convention.  But the  rules of arithmetic have empirical applications and this is what makes them very useful. We think it is absurd to deny 2+2=4, and so it is, but that is  because it is so useful and important to our ways of life - not because it is backed by a super-reality.

Comment: Surely its the other round, that empirical observation has given rise to the rule 2+2=4?  It reflects ordinary reality, if not a super-reality? I can agree that an a system of axioms can be seen as a grammar, but there is still, I think a real distinction between ordinary language and mathematics.